# Suppose a large number of N people flip a coin 100 times, how would you find the percentage of them that would get less than 45 heads?

Tags: statistics

Assume that the probability of 100 people is big enough that the trial can be approximated by normal distribution.

In the problem, N is unknown.

I think you would need to use the 68-95-99.9 rule, but I'm not sure exactly how/what formula I would use. Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of heads we obtain in $100$ flips.

**Normal approximation without continuity correction:**

$$\mu=np$$

$$\sigma^2=npq$$

where $$\frac{X-\mu}{\sqrt{npq}}\sim N(0,1)$$

Then we have

$$\begin{align*}
P(Z\lt 45)
&=\Phi\left({\frac{45-50}{\sqrt{100\cdot0.5\cdot0.5}}}\right)\\\\
&=\Phi(-1)\\\\
&\approx0.1587
\end{align*}$$

**With continuity correction:**

$$\begin{align*}
P(Z\lt 45)
&=\Phi\left({\frac{44.5-50}{\sqrt{100\cdot0.5\cdot0.5}}}\right)\\\\
&=\Phi(-1.1)\\\\
&\approx0.1335
\end{align*}$$

**Exact probability using binomial distribution:**

$$\begin{align*}
P(X<45)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{44} {n\choose k}{0.5^
k}{0.5^{n-k}}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{44} {100 \choose k}{0.5^
k}{0.5^{100-k}}\\\\
&=0.1356265
\end{align*}$$

This can be calculated in R:

```
> sum(dbinom(0:44,100,.5))
[1] 0.1356265
```